# zone.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null at user.service.ts:32

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase into my angular typescript file to check if a particular user exists on the database. When I try passing the email id to the database and retrieve corresponding password to check for validation, I get this error:

> zone.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of
>   null
>       at user.service.ts:32

Following is the user.service.ts

```js
getPassword(email:string)
  {
    this.db.database.ref('/facility/Akhilesh').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value', (snapshot) => {
     line 32<-- console.log(snapshot.val().password);
      this.userpassword = snapshot.val().password;
    })
    return this.userpassword.toString();
```

Following is the typescript file from which I am passing the email and returning the password for verification:

```js
const verify=this.verifyuser(instForm.value['facilityId']);
    if(verify==instForm.value['facilityPasskey'])
       {this.router.navigateByUrl('/login/olduser');}
       
       
 verifyuser(email: string){
  
    
    this.userService.getPassword(email);
  }
```

[image: database]

Can someone correct where I have made a mistake, also how can I check if the email id exists on the database and return a error value if no user exists?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(snapshot.val())`

Comment: @AdritaSharma  console.log(snapshot.val()) gives output "null"

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly says `snapshot.val()` is null.

You have to add a check here, like this:

```
if(snapshot.val()){
    this.userpassword = snapshot.val().password
}
```

Comment: This works when I don't have the data in the database. But the entered credentials exists in the database and still it returns a null value. I have attached the image of the database to the question.